# Style legend tag as block

Tags: html, css

I've setup a demo of my problem at the following url: http://jsfiddle.net/YHHg7/4/

I'm trying to do the following:

```
legend {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

However it seems all browsers ignore the `display: block` on a legend tag. Is this the correct behaviour for this tag or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can use `display: contents` to remove all browser styles with an inner wrapper div for styling http://jsfiddle.net/d20k51vb/3/. see https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents regarding accessibility concerns in safari.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<legend>` is a block-level element by default, so whether you include `display: block` there's no difference. However, it's treated specially together with `<fieldset>` by browsers as a label for a fieldset.

To "detach" it from the `<fieldset>` you can give it a non-static position, or float it, or even just play a little more with its margins. Results can be a little unpredictable, though, again due to the special treatment of both elements.

Comment: Cheers, gave me the result I was after.

Comment: Is today, legend a block element, on HTML 5? http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#the-legend-element

Comment: @MEM: It would seem so: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#flow-content-0 The document you linked to is not W3C HTML5, but WHATWG HTML, but nevertheless it seems to agree: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html#flow-content-3

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was just styling a complex legend, and I notice that no more block elements are allowed. It's kind of a drawback in this case. I guess I have to use other elements then legend, OR, I hack it with a <span> to contain <section> and <aside> and <div>. Neither seems truly reasonable to me. :/ (`aside`, `div`, all inside a legend? are you crazy? No. It is really a complex set of instructions, to help the user to choose the right option on that fieldset).

Comment: @MEM: "a complex set of instructions, to help the user to choose the right option on that fieldset" You shouldn't be using a legend for that in the first place. Just use p elements or whatever complex structure you have in mind.

Comment: But is is, a legend. It is something that is describing what comes next, and it is something that is specifically related with form fill elements. I can totally justify that semantically. But for the sake of the available options, I will, change that to something else indeed. Still, I would not say I'm thrilled about it...

Comment: @MEM: No, that's not what a legend is. Like the spec says, a legend is nothing more than a caption. That's why it only accepts phrasing content in the first place. I don't know how anyone could possibly justify your use case, but good luck.

Comment: Indeed. If I want to make "as they told me to do", I'm sure there's a reason why they accept only phrasing content, and I'm sure that reason lies on the fact they do interpret legend, just as you said. That doesn't mean, however, that I have to agree with the semantic definition of legend, as they propose.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best thing you can do to control legend is just leave it as a semantic fixture only.

CSS:

```
legend {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And then use a span inside it to control all of your desired styling:

HTML:

```
<legend><span>Span to the rescue!</span></legend>
```

CSS:

```
legend span {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Clean, semantic, and generally easily manipulated across different browsers

Comment: Why use a `span` only to style it as `display: block`? Just use a `div`...

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the `width` attribute if you want the red line to go all the way across.

```
legend {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't really answer my question as I need `display: block` because margin & padding alterations won't apply to the element.

Comment: Floating the legend *and* applying `width: 100%` seems to do the trick. Then any other styling apply to an interior block element like header or div tag.

Answer (score 0):

A `legend` is a block-level element by default.  If I add the width back in using Chrome (Dev channel), the width of the legend is changed appropriately.

If you're instead wondering about the `margin` style, a `legend` can only have its left or right margins set, and that would place it relative to the `fieldset` its's contained in.  If you want to add spacing to the other elements, then you would probably want to add padding to the `fieldset` itself.