# Does legend do accept block elements?

Tags: html

I have this layout where, semantically, the legend of a complex fieldset, has a little description.

It seems that the legend just accepts:
*Phrasing content* (btw, is the the same as *inline* elements?).
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html#flow-content-3

Or more officially:
w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#flow-content-0

Would it be acceptable to change the `display` property of a legend to `Block`; ?

Or is it preferable to do it differently?

I mean, could I have some drawbacks (that I'm not seeing at the moment) for changing a legend to block, and allow some `<p>` and `<div>` and `<aside>` inside it?

Comment: Just stick a `span` in there (keeping it valid afaik) and display both as block. Edit: There's nothing wrong with changing an element's display property.

Comment: If I stick a span, I can as well drop the fieldset and use a div instead. I could use divs everywhere, but the main purpose is to, indeed, have some semantic meaning.

Comment: @MEM - there is nothing wrong with using a span in a legend like `<legend><span>text</span></legend>`. Indeed, it is the only way I have achieved cross-browser styling of the stubborn legend element. If a `<fieldset>` is best semantically, go for it!

Comment: While I still feel that as a hack, having span surrounding block elements, I have to agree with you (both) that, semantically, the footprint of that is not that huge. But, is it still valid on something like: `<legend><span><div><p>content description</p><p>more legend details</p><aside><p>some aside content, but still related with legend</p></aside></div></span>` ?

Comment: @MEM - I don't know how best to interpret the docs to give a definitive answer on that :) - It seems absurd to wrap all that in a legend though! I don't think it would help provide any semantic meaning.

Comment: As I said. It's a very complex legend. :) Ie. "On this next boxes, you have several choices. According to your level, you may choose the one who best fits your interests. Please have a look at the following table to help you out..." And so we go... :) But, worry not, we will end up on thinking something else for it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would it be acceptable to change the display property of a legend to Block; ?

Of course it would be, but -

> I mean, could I have some drawbacks (that I'm not seeing at the moment) for changing a legend to block, and allow some `<p>` and `<div>` and `<aside>` inside it?

- that would still not make this valid HTML.

*Formatting* an element via CSS does not change anything about what content is allowed for that element *structurally* in HTML.

So the answer is No - you can not put `p`, `div` or `aside` elements into a `legend` if you want valid HTML, no matter how you format it with CSS.

The spec is quite clear about what constitutes [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) - and *that's* what you can put inside a `legend`, and not anything else that is not categorized as phrasing content.

> [from comments] As I said. It's a very complex legend. :) Ie. "On this next boxes, you have several choices. According to your level, you may choose the one who best fits your interests. Please have a look at the following table to help you out..."

That should not be a `legend` IMHO.

Think of a legend more like a headline of some sort.

Additional text that explains what choices the user has etc., should *follow* the legend - and then use can use `div`, `p` etc. because the content model of `fieldset` is [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1).

Comment: I had no idea the OP posted this question - that would explain [their comments on this related answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630574/style-legend-tag-as-block/5630621?noredirect=1#comment40325421_5630621). Not a terribly productive conversation, as you can imagine.

Comment: As stated also on the comments mentioned, I still believe that the semantic interpretation of legend is wrong, even if we look to the word etymology, but, if we wish to follow the rules, then, I have to agree with both of you, (while imho stupidly) we **can't** do that. I will accept and mark this as useful. Thank you.

Comment: The semantics _defined_ by HTML do not always match the "real-world" meaning of the word that is used as tag name. And your proposed "hack" of using `<legend><span><div><p>content ...` would still not be valid - legend can contain span, but span can not contain div and p. And even if it could, it would not make those descendants allowed in legend all of a sudden.

Comment: Go it. :) Thank you, really, for providing such complete answer, including the miss interpretation that I wrongly had about the consequences of changing the display property of an element. :) If I could, I would touch the useful button twice. :)